# Swift Pair of struct

Tags: arrays, swift

To Match card and Emoji. There things that I do not understand. It is generating two identical cards.  I did not understand how it is getting the same emoji when both cards identifiers are the same.  I did not understand the behavior of the `func emoji`.  See what is shown at the result section.

When both identifiers are the same it does not call the function:

```
import Foundation

struct Card {
    var isFaceUp = false
    var isMatched = false
    var identifier: Int

    static var identifierFactory = 0
    static func getUniqueIdentifer() -> Int {
        identifierFactory += 1
        return identifierFactory
    }
    init() {
        self.identifier = Card.getUniqueIdentifer()
    }
}
var cards = Array<Card>()

for _ in 1...6 {
    let card = Card()
    cards += [card, card]

}
for card in cards {
    print("card \(card)")
}
var emojiChoices = ["", "", "", "", "", "⏳", "☕︎", "", "☪️", "", "", ""]
var emoji = [Int: String]()
func emoji(for card: Card) -> String {
    print("Card Id: \(card.identifier)")
    if  emoji[card.identifier] == nil {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojiChoices.count)))
        print("RandomIndex \(randomIndex)")
         print("In Card Id: \(card.identifier)")
        emoji[card.identifier] = emojiChoices.remove(at: randomIndex )
         print("id \(emoji[card.identifier] )")
    }
    return emoji[card.identifier] ?? "?"
}

var card = cards[0]
var emo1 = emoji(for: card)
print("emo1 \(emo1)")
card = cards[4]
var emo2 = emoji(for: card)
print("emo2 \(emo2)")
card = cards[2]
var emo3 = emoji(for: card)
card = cards[3]
var emo4 = emoji(for: card)
print("\(emo1) , \(emo2), \(emo3) and \(emo4)")
```

Result:

```
Card Id: 1
RandomIndex 4
In Card Id: 1
id Optional("")
emo1 
Card Id: 3
RandomIndex 1
In Card Id: 3
id Optional("")
emo2 
Card Id: 2
RandomIndex 1
In Card Id: 2
id Optional("")
Card Id: 2
 , ,  and
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused that the last two cards are both butterflies ().

This loop:

```
for _ in 1...6 {
    let card = Card()
    cards += [card, card]
}
```

is adding pairs of cards to the `cards` array.  Because of this, `card[0]` and `card[1]` are the same (have the same `identifier`), `card[2]` and `card[3]` are the same, and `card[4]` and `card[5]` are the same.

So in the end, you are printing `card[0]`, `card[4]`, `card[2]`, and `card[3]`.  Since `card[2]` and `card[3]` have the same `identifier`, both will display the same `emoji`.

---

**How does `func emoji` return the same emoji for the same identifier?**

`func emoji` is populating the `emoji` dictionary.  That dictionary is a mapping from a card `identifier` to an emoji character.  If a card identifier is already in the dictionary, it returns the value that is there.  If this is the first time accessing an identifier, it grabs a new random emoji character from the `emojiChoices` array and adds that to the dictionary using the card `identifier` as the key.

Repeated calls to `func emoji` with the same identifier will return the same emoji character, because the value will be found in the `emoji` dictionary.

It will help you to understand what is happening if you print the `emoji` dictionary after each call to `func emoji`:

```
var card = cards[0]
var emo1 = emoji(for: card)
print("emoji dict is now \(emoji)")
print("emo1 \(emo1)")
card = cards[4]
var emo2 = emoji(for: card)
print("emoji dict is now \(emoji)")
print("emo2 \(emo2)")
card = cards[2]
var emo3 = emoji(for: card)
print("emoji dict is now \(emoji)")
card = cards[3]
var emo4 = emoji(for: card)
print("emoji dict is now \(emoji)")
print("\(emo1) , \(emo2), \(emo3) and \(emo4)")
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Card Id: 1
> RandomIndex 1
> In Card Id: 1
> id Optional("")
> emoji dict is now [1: ""]
> emo1 
> Card Id: 3
> RandomIndex 7
> In Card Id: 3
> id Optional("☪️")
> emoji dict is now [3: "☪️", 1: ""]
> emo2 ☪️
> Card Id: 2
> RandomIndex 1
> In Card Id: 2
> id Optional("")
> emoji dict is now [2: "", 3: "☪️", 1: ""]
> Card Id: 2
> emoji dict is now [2: "", 3: "☪️", 1: ""]
>  , ☪️,  and
> ```

Comment: But the function is changing the randomIndex which gives different emoji. why ma I getting same emoji for same id

Comment: The first time you use `identifier` `1`, it checks the dictionary and sees that that identifier is not in the dictionary, so the look up returns `nil`.  So, it grabs a random emoji from `emojiChoices` and adds that emoji to the dictionary: `emoji[1] = ""`.  The next time `func emoji` is called with `1`, it finds the `""` in the dictionary, so it doesn't use the random function.  It just returns the `""`.

Comment: The dictionay has one key for two cards of same identifier.  how to associate one key to two cards of the same identifier

Comment: @JeylaniOsman, I'm not sure I understand your question.  Do you want the key to be the identifier and the values to be all cards with that identifier?  Like `[Card]`?  How would you use that?